# Why is there gap above the form?

Tags: css

I want to achieve this:

[image]

I have achieved this:

[image]

I don't understand why is there gap above the login form? Also why the fields and 'LOGIN' button not aligned correctly? The page is live at http://goo.gl/OpAB4V

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
<header>
<img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_02.png" alt="">
<div id="header-login">
<form id="header-login-form">
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="header-login-form-field">
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="header-login-form-field">
<input name="submit" type="image" src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_05.png">
</form>
</div>
</header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(images/tellerest-homepage-design2_04.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
#container {
background-image: url(images/tellerest-homepage-design2_01.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: center top;
height: 1000px;
}
header { width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
#header-login { float: right; text-align: right; height: 10px; margin: 15px; vertical-align: bottom;}
#header-login-form { padding: 0;}
#header-login-form input { margin: 0 0 0 10px; overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: move ur div header login http://screencast.com/t/Hw6FtcNN4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. HTML changes - move `<div id="header-login">` before the `<img>` -

   ```
   <div id="header-login">
    <form id="header-login-form">
     <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="header-login-form-field">
     <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="header-login-form-field">
     <input name="submit" type="image" src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_05.png">
    </form>
   </div>
   <img src="images/tellerest-homepage-design_02.png" alt="">
   ```

   Floats are funny this way, the float itself should mostly appear in the code before the content beside which it floats.
2. CSS changes - add `float: right` to `#header-login`. Add `vertical-align: bottom` to all `input` there, or `vertical-align: top` to the input fields, because each of them likely varies in its implicit default value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

A div tag is a block tag, so it can't position itself to the right of your image. You have to define a width to the div that contains the form and a behavior/position

```
#header-login{
 width:500px;
 float:right;
}
```

`img{
    float:left;
   }`

Comment: Just to make it clearer : a block tag (as div), as width: 100%; by default. That's why it goes under the image.

Comment: Move `<div id="header-login">` before the `<img>`, or else `float: right` sometimes works unexpectedly.

Comment: edit : make the img float too. Or make the both display:inline-block;

Comment: @audre7 - no need to float the image as well, see my comment above.

Comment: Okay so placing image below the login div worked solved the problem. But why are the inputs of form not aligning correctly?

Comment: @lakshkhamesra - add `vertical-align: top` to input fields, or `vertical-align: bottom` to all of the `input` elements there.

Comment: @PhistucK How do I mark you as the correct answerer?

Answer (score -1):

Give your header image to float:left and heder-login to float right

```
img{
float:left;
}

#header-login{
 float:right;
}
```

Comment: You would say img instead of .img ?

Comment: so it's header img, no element has the class ".img" there.